# showing image+text in suggestBox()

Tags: gwt, suggestbox

I am trying to display an icon along with text in suggestion drop down using SuggestBox and MultiWordSuggestOracle following code:

```
public class Suggestions implements Suggestion {

    private String suggestion;

    public Suggestions(){}

    public Suggestions(String suggestion){
        this.suggestion = new String( suggestion );
    }
    @Override
    public String getDisplayString() {
        return ( suggestion + " <img src='/images/image.png'/> " );
    }
    @Override
    public String getReplacementString() {
        return suggestion;
    }}
```

And in onModuleLoad function contain following code:

```
 MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle(){
          @Override
          public boolean isDisplayStringHTML() {
              return true;
          }};  
          oracle.add(new Suggestions("A").getDisplayString());
      SuggestBox suggestionBox = new SuggestBox(oracle);
```

Problem : html code is printed as normal text. Could you guys please suggest whats wrong with the code?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your Suggestion class is never used !

The multiword oracle has just the display string, and create his own Suggestion items.

Just override the methode createSuggestion in the oracle :

```
MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle(){
      @Override
      public boolean isDisplayStringHTML() {
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      protected MultiWordSuggestion createSuggestion(String replacementString, String displayString) {
         return new Suggestions(replacementString);
      }
};  
oracle.add(new Suggestions("A").getDisplayString());
SuggestBox suggestionBox = new SuggestBox(oracle);
```

Comment: thank you! I have couple of doubts..
1. How above this suggestion thing is working?
2. My code is still not working. It was throwing type mismatch error saying 'cannot convert from Suggestions to MultiWordSuggestOracle.MultiWordSuggestion'. when I changed 'Suggestions' class to extend 'MultiWordSuggetion' class, error is gone but code is still not working. When I select any one suggestions in the suggestion box, image tag appears as text. (image tag is not visible in the drop down). Thank you!

Comment: My code worked after I replace <img> tag in 'getDisplayString' in Suggestion class with GWT image widget. And used 'oracle.add("A")' instead of 'oracle.add(new Suggestions("A").getDisplayString())'  Still I am interested to know how Suggestion thing works internally. Thank you for the lead.

Comment: The suggestbox is a textbox, you can only display html suggestions, it's can be usefull for display in bold the query text, but in fine, the suggestion is a text value.

Comment: Why did you use the gwt image widget ?

Comment: I wanted to display image along with text,the sort that appear on facebook when you search someone. <img> tag was not working, so I used Image widget (I am guessing, GWT was unable to interpret html <img> tag).

Comment: I understand the desire to display an icon, but the suggest didn't display a gwt widget. So can you show your new code ?
Thanks.

Comment: Sure! Adding it as new answer, it is too long for comment.

Answer (score 1):

Below is what I did to get image+text in suggestion drop down.

```
public class Suggestions implements Suggestion {

    private String suggestion;

    public Suggestions(){}

    public Suggestions(String suggestion){
        this.suggestion = new String( suggestion );
    }
    @Override
    public String getDisplayString() {
        return ( suggestion + new Image('/images/image.png') );
    }
    @Override
    public String getReplacementString() {
        return suggestion;
    }}

OnModuleLoad function is: 

MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle(){
      @Override
      public boolean isDisplayStringHTML() {
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      protected MultiWordSuggestion createSuggestion(String replacementString, String displayString) {
         return new Suggestions(replacementString);
      }
};  
oracle.add("A");
SuggestBox suggestionBox = new SuggestBox(oracle);
```

Comment: Why to you do :   
new String(suggestion) ?  
  
You create an instance of the Image for just call the toString() of the class.  
It's the same as : suggestion + "<img src='/images/image.png'/>";  
But you don't instantiate a new object just for it.

Comment: @PatriceDeSaintSteban initially I used suggestion +  "<img src='/images/image.png'/>", but due to some reason it wasn't working. Thats why I used Image object. And now that i realized, forgive me for using "new String(suggestion)". I started coding after a long time (almost 7 years).